# How to Parse JSON to String Array

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have this JSON

```
{
    "tags": [
        "php",
        "javascript",
        "object",
        "angularjs",
        "html-select"]
}

JSONArray tagsJSONArray = jobj.getJSONArray("tags");
    tags = new String[tagsJSONArray.length()];
    for(int x = 0; x < tagsJSONArray.length(); x++){            
        //tags[x] = tagsJSONArray[x].toString();
    }
```

And I want to save the tags to my String Array. The JSON looks different from other JSONArray that I used to know. Please help me. I'm stuck here.

Comment: what's the different?

Answer (score 1):

use [getString(int index);](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString%28int%29)

```
   for(int x = 0; x < tagsJSONArray.length(); x++){            
       tags[x] = tagsJSONArray.getString(x)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray tagsJSONArray = jobj.getJSONArray("tags");
    tags = new String[tagsJSONArray.length()];
    for(int x = 0; x < tagsJSONArray.length(); x++){            
        tags[x] = tagsJSONArray.get(x).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a **JSONObject** first...

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray);

JSONArray tagsJSONArray = jobj.getJSONArray("tags");
    tags = new String[tagsJSONArray.length()];
    for(int x = 0; x < tagsJSONArray.length(); x++){            
        //tags[x] = tagsJSONArray[x].toString();
    }
```